# Can't create overloaded constructor in sub-class

Tags: java, class, constructor, overloading

I've defined a sub-class and want to have two constructors with different parameters. It looks like this

```
public class GraphNode extends Entity{
   protected String id;

   public GraphNode(PVector pos, String id) {
       super(pos,0);
       this.id = id;
   }

   public GraphNode(PVector pos, String id, List<GraphEdge>) {
       this(pos, id);
       //do something else
   }
}
```

The compiler keeps telling me that:

> Duplicate method GraphNode(PVector, String) in type 
>        GraphNode

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This does not look like the full story? And Specify variable name for the List<GraphEdge> edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give your third argument a variable name:

```
public GraphNode(PVector pos, String id, List<GraphEdge> list)
```

Comment: I should really take a break, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
public class GraphNode extends Entity{
   protected String id;

   public GraphNode(PVector pos, String id) {
       super(pos,0);
       this.id = id;
   }

   public GraphNode(PVector pos, String id, List<GraphEdge> list) {
       this(pos, id);
       //do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: If was hard for me to spot the difference between yours and op's method. Looked like those games "find the 7 differences" :)